# Evaluate a simple spreadsheet

Tags: code-golf, matrix, data-structures

### Rules

1. No cell range references (`A2:B3`).
2. Maximum 9 rows and 9 columns.
3. No circular references or formula errors.
4. Empty cells evaluate to `0`.
5. Data are numbers only, but may be taken as strings.
6. Formulas are strings.

### Implementation choices

You must state your choices in these matters:

7. Require formulas to be prefixed with any single character, e.g. `=` – or not.
8. The leftmost cell of the second row is `A2` or `R2C1`, as per the two conventions used by Excel et al.
9. Require any single-character pre- or suffix in cell references, e.g. `$` – or not.
10. One of null, empty string, empty list, etc., (but not `0`) to represent empty cells.
11. Language of your submission (spreadsheet managers are not allowed).
12. Language for the formulas (may differ from the above).*
13. Brownie points or cookies for explaining your solution.

### Examples

Choices: 7: `=`; 8: `A2`; 9: none; 10: `""`; 12: Excel Formula Language

#### In:

```
[[       2, 3],
 ["=A1+B1",""]]
```

#### Out:

```
[[2,3],
 [5,0]]
```

#### In:

```
[[       2,"=A1+B2"],
 ["=A1+B1",      ""]]
```

#### Out:

```
[[2,2],
 [4,0]]
```

#### In:

```
[[ 3, 4,"=A1*B1"],
 [ 2, 5,"=A2*B2"],
 ["","","=C1+C2"]]
```

#### Out:

```
[[3,4,12],
 [2,5,10],
 [0,0,22]]
```

#### In:

```
[["","=2*B2*B3"     ,""],
 [ 3,"=A1+(A2+C2)/2", 2],
 [ 1,"=C1+(A3+C3)/2", 5]]
```

#### Out:

```
[[0,15,  0],
 [3, 2.5,2],
 [1, 3  ,5]]
```

---

<sup>* The formula language must be [PPCG admissible](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2073/43319), but you only have to support cell references plus criteria 3 and 4 there, wiz. addition and primeness determination.</sup>

Comment: Is submitted an answer in Excel/VBA disallowed? `Expand array to cells, evaluate.`

Comment: @carusocomputing If you are not just letting Excel do its thing, then feel free to post.

Comment: Can we have cells be zero-based? As in, `R0C0`?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien No, it has to be one of *the two conventions used by Excel et al.*

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript, <del>125</del> <del>112</del> 105 bytes

To use, add `f=` at the beginning and invoke like `f(argument)`.

```
a=>a.map(b=>b.map(p=>+p?p:p?eval(p.replace(/[A-I][1-9]/g,m=>`a[${m[1]-1}][${(m.charCodeAt(0)-65)}]`)):0))
```

#### Choices:

7. Does not require `=`.
8. The left most cell of second row is `A2`.
9. Does not require any prefix or suffix.
10. `""` (Empty String) to denote empty cell.
11. JavaScript.
12. JavaScript.
13. Cookies.

#### Explanation:

This solution iterates over all the cells of the worksheet (each element of the sub-arrays of the given array) and if non-empty String is found, replaces its cell references with the corresponding references in terms of the given array and evaluates the expression with `eval()` (yeah, [that evil thing that haunts you in your nightmares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)). This solution assumes that the constants provided in the input array are of Integer type.

#### Test Cases

```js
f=a=>a.map(b=>b.map(p=>+p?p:p?eval(p.replace(/[A-I][1-9]/g,m=>`a[${m[1]-1}][${(m.charCodeAt(0)-65)}]`)):0))

console.log(f([[1,2,3],["A1+B1+C1",10,11]]));
console.log(f([[1,2,5,4,6,89,0],[0,1,2,3,"A2+A1",5,6]]));
console.log(f([[1,2,4,5],["A1/B1*C1+A1+Math.pow(5,B1)",2,3,4]]));
```

Comment: Very nice. Here: .

Comment: Any reason you can't use `/\w\d/g` for your regex?

Comment: @powelles `\w` matches digits too, and `\d` matches 0 too, both things you don't want in this case. `/[A-I][1-9]/g` should work though

Comment: @LarsW `/\w\d/g` produces the exact same results in the test cases. Also using a template literal in the eval portion could save a handful of bytes.

Comment: @powelles yes, but the test cases may be incomplete. Anyway, I assumed the chosen rules need to be followed; but they may just be input restrictions (or both), so that can be the problem too

Comment: Thanks @LarsW ! This is my regEx implementation, so I am a noob at it currently. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Thanks @powelles !  I have edited the solution to include the template literal syntax however the other suggestion you suggested don't work well for me. They fail at some test cases.

Comment: You can also change `m.charAt(1)-1` to `m[1]-1`

Comment: @powelles Thanks! Implemented!

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, <s>265 263 259 258 257 240 224 222 213 202</s> 196 bytes

featuring [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive), a [recursive anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2480242/6442316) and [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```php
function f(&$a){array_walk_recursive($a,$p=function(&$c)use($a,&$p){eval('$c='.preg_replace_callback("#R(.)C(.)#",function($m)use($a,&$p){$d=$a[$m[1]-1][$m[2]-1];$p($d);return$d;},$c?:0).';');});}
```

or

```php
function f(&$a){array_walk_recursive($a,$p=function(&$c)use($a,&$p){eval('$c='.preg_replace_callback("#R(.)C(.)#",function($m)use($a,&$p){return$p($a[$m[1]-1][$m[2]-1]);},$c?:0).';');return$c;});}
```

operates on input: call by reference. [Test it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c57d5272bbf563f7197a056a308249f0f96b4432).

- no expression prefix
- reference format `R2C1`, no prefix
- anything falsy for empty cell
- evaluates any (lowercase) PHP expression, including all arithmetics

**breakdown** (first version)

```php
function f(&$a)
{
    array_walk_recursive($a,                    # walk through elements ...
        $p=function(&$c)use($a,&$p){            # use array $a and recursive $p
            eval('$c='.                             # 3. evaluate expression
                preg_replace_callback('#R(.)C(.)#', # 2. replace references with ...
                function($m)use($a,&$p){
                    $d=$a[$m[1]-1][$m[2]-1];            # $d=content of referenced cell
                    $p($d);                             # recursive evaluation
                    return$d;                           # return $d
                },$c?:0)                            # 1. replace empty with 0
                .';'
            );
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: +1 Very nice; . You say standard arithmetics, but really any reasonable PHP expression would work, no?

Comment: @Adám Now that you mention it ... as long as it´s lowercase, yes. Though `max(range(A1,A3))` might be confusing. :D

Comment: Nice golf took me quite long to find anything: `$d=$c;preg_match($x="#[A-Z](.)#",$c=$c[0]` to `preg_match($x="#[A-Z](.)#",$c=($d=$c)[0]` should save 1 byte.

Comment: Would it be possible to include a [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php "PHP – TIO Nexus") link?

Comment: @Christoph took me a new approach to fix the second example ... and saved a lot in the process ... plus further golfing

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, <s>119</s> <s>115</s> 95 bytes

```
(m=#/.""->0)//.s_String:>ToExpression@StringReplace[s,"R"~~x_~~"C"~~y_:>"m[["<>{x,",",y,"]]"}]&
```

Choices:

7. No prefix.
8. `R2C1` style.
9. No prefix or suffix.
10. `""` for empty cells.
11. Mathematica.
12. Mathematica. Arbitrary arithmetic expressions that don't use variables of the form `RxCy` and don't have side effects should work.

#### Explanation

```
(m=#/.""->0)
```

We start by replacing all empty strings in the input (`#`) with zeros and storing the result in `m`, because we'll need this again in another place.

```
...//.s_String:>...
```

*Repeatedly* replace any remaining string `s` with the following...

```
...StringReplace[s,"R"~~x_~~"C"~~y_:>...]
```

Match any substrings of the form `RxCy` in `s` and replace them with...

```
..."m[["<>{x,",",y,"]]"}
```

Which gives `m[[x,y]]`, which uses `x` and `y` as indices into the matrix `m`.

```
...ToExpression@...
```

Finallz, evaluate this string as a Mathematica expression.

Comment: Cool. I thought that it would take a little longer than that... Any way to try this?

Comment: @Adám Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work in Mathics, so without a copy of Mathematica, probably not.

Comment: Still waiting for the builtin...

Comment: @YSC Excel, 0 bytes.

Comment: @Adám That would not be competing per the rules of this challenge. Also, I think Martin deserves a cookie.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I know; I wrote them. Build-ins are forbidden, as any language with a build-in would be a spreadsheet manager, no? He didn't specify preference, but; .

Answer (score 3):

### Clojure, <s>263</s> 281 bytes

Oh damn without that `apply map vector` the result is in transpose, as `A2` is alphabetically before `B1`.

```
#(apply map vector(partition(count(% 1))(for[v(vals(loop[C(into{}(mapcat(fn[i r](map(fn[j v][(str j i)(or v"0")])"ABCDEFGHI"r))(rest(range))%))P[]](if(= C P)C(recur(into(sorted-map)(for[[k v]C][k(reduce(fn[r[K V]](clojure.string/replace r K V))v C)]))C))))](eval(read-string v)))))
```

Examples:

```
(def f #(...))

(f [["2" "3"]["(+ A1 B1)" nil]])
([2 3] [5 0])

(f [[nil ,"(* 2 B2 B3)"                ,nil],
    ["3" ,"(+ A1 (/ (+ A2 C2) 2))"     ,"2"],
    ["1" ,"(-> A3 (+ C3) (/ 2) (+ C1))","5"]])
([0 15N 0] [3 5/2 2] [1 3 5])
```

7. Formulas are S-expressions
8. `A2`
9. No, `(+ A1 A2)` is fine
10. `nil` and `false` work as empty cells, but empty string do not
11. Clojure
12. S-expressions (Clojure + any built-in macros)

An example of thread first macro:

```
(macroexpand '(-> A3 (+ C3) (/ 2) (+ C1)))
(+ (/ (+ A3 C3) 2) C1)
```

Starting value of `C` in the loop is a hash-map, keys are cell names and values are original values. Then all cell references are replaced by contents of referenced cells until we have converged (`P`revious = `C`urrent), then cells are evaluated and the flat structure is partitioned back into a nested list.

Would be cool to find a solution where `A1`, `A2` etc. are actually callable functions, then `(* 2 B2 B3)` could be rewritten to `(* 2 (B2) (B3))` and executed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/clojure#ZVE7T8MwEN7zK05Gle4gpSQRI0iteYqlE4vlwUqcKm2II8eJhBC/vZxTFsrJw935e1k@YmVrqOECTd@3n/BhephsGZzH3vjQhMZ1WLqxC7iAjAhr59WEk2kHbJ3rlcSmC@7rG5lZmoB1pxrwOo6x38OkFQ7Bwx4aQudhEjeCNIn1Rj48Pj2/vArPst4OAb3pdpZoQbRVWmNT4x1I2JLk63L0sxMOzgdbLVn/FEYd2EJqdWBQNZY2unr1Bu@sULZuP3p7zf5Nt1t527emtOCBr4kmkByEJHFptPwmljDV8oSGieZKkgR7XoS2A6xBKZELEIXQSuAVrDPYZCSga1rNWmdQ3kIq8BJy2PApGHhWaSSmyZ@dYvVIm9VxBbHJQeYEOf0qpBziPy2bact7WBeRJAuKdObFgT9PpOJWxJjH4w8)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 51 bytes

```apl
⍎¨({((⍴⍵)↑⍉⎕A∘.,1↓⎕D),¨'←',¨⍵}{0::⍵⋄×≢⍵:⍕⍎⍕⍵⋄0}¨)⍣≡
```

7. None
8. `A2`
9. None
10. Empty string
11. APL
12. APL

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVKxjhMxEO33K0bbOCsMXHZFc10IkRCKALG5Kkrhy04Soz1vZDt3iaJ0KCKCjUAoOhqKu2vyAYeoaHJ/4h8J480VFJTcyPaMx0@e98YW4/xxNhN5MdzvB275xZXr3bY2r9VceevKn5FbfnXlyq03Dffx@xNed8tvtHkR8d2WEZyRJ9hifnR8TN59@nB36VbXFNJ2Q5dVq88fLXbbyJU3bnW137vyB9gRgsKppUAjQi4VGkAlTnM8nMk@wmkxxQwyaca5mAVRvxjPwIjcBvPFAZo22p2gR0wICYUKghgSos5epW9eM2Dpy1arQ/5dKz1pdxh3n38T/cOA/2JeCp6LfCIs3kvB6VijMbJQBoTKQGgt1LBSdQZSgYChlhlcSDvyOalhhCKTamiC96ZQvq3dbhjyML67fO5nElIhHoY9zniNmJ80U6gnEWfQhcTDfrly@@hpI4ZmHHKI/4Wr/4VLoJkQ7lmvx@4VaHEBvmWBGSFa/w/o3dcbnwLPCR7CfOF@oc5R26o42AIab9twJqyW02AAFRl4WKvUT1T15QYT1bf0bH8A)

`⍎¨` Evaluate each cell of the result from

`(`…`)⍣≡` continuous application of the following two functions until nothing more changes

`{` first anonymous function to be applied…

`0` on any
  `::` error:
   `⍵` return the argument unmodified

`⋄` now try;

`⍵` if the argument's
  `≢` tally:
  `×` is positive
  `:` then:
   `⍕` stringify
   `⍎` the evaluated
   `⍕` stringified
   `⍵` argument

`⋄` else;

`0` return zero

`}¨` … to each cell

`{` second anonymous function to be applied…

`'←',¨` prepend an assignment arrow to each cell of
  `⍵` the argument

`(`…`),¨` prepend the following to each cell of that

`1↓` drop the first of
   `⎕D` the string of all **D**igits (i.e. zero)

`⎕A` With all the letters of the **A**lphabet going down,
   `∘.,` make a concatenation table (with the remaining digits going right)

`⍉` transpose (to get increasing numbers down, progressing letters right)

`(`…`)↑` take the upper left submatrix with the size of…

`⍴` the size of
    `⍵` the argument

`}` … to the the previous function's result.

Comment: Your explanations are always beautiful, thanks, makes me want to learn APL beyond what little I know from reading these answers.

Comment: @carusocomputing Thank you. I'll be happy to assist you. Feel free to questions and requests in [the APL chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/apl). I'll help you get set up too if you need that.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) <strike>273,265,263</strike>, 259 bytes

```python
import re
def g(m):x=m.group();return's[%d][%d]'%(int(x[1])-1,ord(x[0])-65)
e=enumerate
while'='in`s`:
    for x,i in e(s):
        for i,j in e(i):
            try:s[x][i]=0if not j else float(eval(re.sub('\w\d',g,str(j)).strip('=')))
            except:pass
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#VY/RaoQwEEXf/YohsJjU1K7K9sHiw9bPyAbWrqONqAlJ7Nqvt5Gl0A4zzOUeGO64SghCOKnyp/fQBYG9OCGSCyiCf84Ses6TOmcvOeGQSw4CsgDqHRRJXTzAScpNTUZbDxajFjvo6cTKtZrS3urFUPZm0S92jp04tHKf@EDV7OkqMsmeM65tG/Qx6NcTi7DCeZnQNh6j@6caMa5iNV/dtYz2hJ22sHIFagakjj3MX6D48ADqD9jL2@/SiVUKJauj6mDWHgbA0SF0o248xa9mpBZTt3zQ@HK/tDHvufOWDoylYStDQw7G2L@zuN7Q@NI0zm3Ghp/AbdsP)

**Choices:**

7. =
8. A2
9. none
10. ""
11. Python 2.7
12. Python expressions

**Basic explanation:**

For every formula in the sublist, substitute it with the corresponding list (that is, for B1 s[0][1]) index and evaluate the result!

- -4 bytes by changing str() to backticks!

Comment: You didn't add import of re in your answer. Also it doesn't pass this input: `s=[[ 3, 4,"max(A1,B1)"],[ 2, 5,"A2**B2"],[ "", "","C1+C2"]]`

Comment: The input format is `[[ 3, 4,"=max(A1,B1)"],[ 2, 5,"=A2**B2"],[ "", "","=C1+C2"]]` That is there as a part of headers! Check it on the try it online link!

Comment: It should be included in byte count. Just check out other python answers on this site

Comment: Is it? I'm net to codeglof. Thanks for the comment. Will add it.

Comment: As far as the other answers are considered, they havent included the input! I've edit with the bye count of import!

Comment: Nice first answer. Please state your choices. An explanation is worth a treat.

Comment: I was working on pretty similar solution. I won't post it as answer, so you may use it to enhance yours. My solution doesn't force all numbers to be floats and allows integer arithmetics. [Check it  here](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#TdBNa4QwEAbg8/orhsBiUrPWD7YHIYdUKPS61zQHV8dW8IsY291fb5OVQsPk8rzDTMjWDfNkLBgMUOC4Dmgqi0GDLbxRyYoAfr66HiEUYTfCYs0DD@1k4MINOMNdwFPJ652Mp0PXwjhZqAupLlqVWiQ72vuMtGZCuHm@D8CaewF/Xfhd9dRgvKxXGip5etcfTcj7arg2FdyKUKpjo/0Nj7QbLb3Fn2ZaZ5owlWp2Svlkmv@YOHw5M167vNDssRBvNc62mKtl2aRQihBORPb06ion4A8nRHMFuXOZRlRmUZmx54xwyOJEc1CQxokLSx/mUZnv4VnrwP9cMBv3NpDb9gs)

Comment: You are actually working on my solution. Glad that my solution is worth it!

Comment: @Adám Thanks! I've added the edits!

Comment: You meant that for @DeadPossum, no?

Comment: That was for you! @Adám You suggested to add the choices!

Comment: OK. Here is your cookie: . I don't know Python, but does `eval()` really evaluate Excel formulas rather than Python expressions? Oh, and your choices seem to be gone again. Maybe you shouldn't put them inside the code block.

Comment: @Adám No, it does not, this solution evaluates Python expressions

Comment: It evaluates python expressions @Adám. I forget the choices when I edit the solution. I'll have that in mind. Thanks!

Comment: So why do you put them inside the code as a comment, rather than just a normal paragraph in your post?